# Point Inside A Polygon Is Returning That It Is Outside The Polygon

Tags: java, android, polygons

I am trying to determine if a phone is located in this polygon using longitude and latitude.

[image]

It worked on my first test point. My second test point (the green dot) returns that it is outside of the polygon. Since Android cannot use the Polygon class, I created my own using the code I found from a few different sites:

```
public class Polygon {

    private double[] polyY, polyX;
    private int polySides;

    public Polygon( double[] px, double[] py, int ps ) {
        polyX = px;
        polyY = py;
        polySides = ps;
    }
    public boolean contains( double x, double y ) {
        boolean oddTransitions = false;
        for( int i = 0, j = polySides -1; i < polySides; j = i++ ) {
            if( ( polyY[ i ] < y && polyY[ j ] >= y ) || ( polyY[ j ] < y && polyY[ i ] >= y ) ) {
                if( polyX[ i ] + ( y - polyY[ i ] ) / ( polyY[ j ] - polyY[ i ] ) * ( polyX[ j ] - polyX[ i ] ) < x ) {
                    oddTransitions = !oddTransitions;          
                }
            }
        }
        return oddTransitions;
    }
}
```

I query the database to get the longitudes and latitudes from this table:

```
db.execSQL("insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE_POLYGON  + " select null as " + KEY_ROWID
                + ", 0 as " + KEY_BUILDING
                + ", -95.929635 as " + KEY_LONG
                + ", 41.223459 as " + KEY_LAT  
                + " union select null,0,-95.931544, 41.223491"
                + " union select null,0,-95.931587, 41.224734"
                + " union select null,0,-95.929484, 41.224782"
                + " union select null,0,-95.929227, 41.227655"
                + " union select null,0,-95.929184, 41.229656"
                + " union select null,0,-95.926437, 41.23006"
                + " union select null,0,-95.92633, 41.228478"
                + " union select null,0,-95.924141, 41.227413"
                + " union select null,0,-95.920944, 41.22617"
                + " union select null,0,-95.921073, 41.225299"
                + " union select null,0,-95.922811, 41.224008"
                + " union select null,0,-95.92706, 41.22099"
                + " union select null,0,-95.927553, 41.221022"
                + " union select null,0,-95.927811, 41.222943"
                + " union select null,0,-95.929334, 41.222991";
```

Here is the code that is failing:

```
Polygon p = new Polygon(xArray,yArray,numPoints);
if(p.contains(-95.927714, 41.225281)){
    textView.setText("in polygon");
}else{
    textView.setText("outside polygon");
}
```

Output: outside polygon

Other info:
It seems to be working in another app I created.
I am using an emulator and mock locations.
I also created a normal java class so I could use the built in Polygon class, but that 
also says that it is outside the polygon.
I used an online polygon grapher just to be totally sure the point was inside the polygon and it was.
The points go in a clockwise direction.

Why is this point returning "outside polygon"?

Comment: Erm, are you sure you `contains()` method has been implemented correctly?

Comment: Not 100%. I found the same algorithm on 3 other sites and it works on another app I created (so far) so I just assumed it was good enough.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I dry tested your `if` condition with some dummy values, and ran into a divide by zero exception. `polyX[i] = 10,polyY[i] = 10`,`(x,y) = (20,20)` and `polyX[j]=10,polyY[j]=30`.

Comment: The first if condition should protect the inner if from the divide by 0 scenario

Comment: At the *bottom* of each for loop, j should equal i. I know j=i++ is a post-increment and should be doing this correctly but maybe try explicitly setting j=i at the bottom of the for loop outside the if blocks (and remove j=i++ from the for loop itself), or at least check that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. Still outside the polygon.

Comment: Just confirming your definitions. polySides = # of corners the polygon has, polyX[] = horizontal coordinates of corners, polyY[] = vertical coordinates of corners. Does that match your definitions and arrays? Is the first coordinate repeated as the final coordinate?

Comment: No I actually tried repeating the first coordinate and still no luck. Should I be repeating? And yes the deifinitions are correct. I will be gone for a few hours. Thanks for the help. I will be back if you figure anything else out, thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the full purpose of the that sql query above. Could you post the raw values in polyX[] and polyY[] as an update to the question.

Comment: One question I always have to ask: are your Y coordinates "rightside up" (as a human would number them) or "upside down" (as the stupid Java graphics that emulates 30 year old technology numbers them)  .  Sometimes it is thanks to a mishmash (some are one way, some the other) that causes the problem.   BTW, whoever wrote that for loop is too clever by half.

Comment: @user949300 it's definitely the upside down one,that's how Android is. The top left corner is (0,0).

Comment: Girish, that was the quickest way to show you all the points without having to type them all out. I can change it when I get back to that computer, though.

Comment: Maybe it'd be more robust to construct the poly, then split it recursively along edges until you have only convex polygons. Then do a point/edge classification for each edge of each polygon to see if one of them contains the point (use a 'safety margin' for edge cases)

Comment: Thanks for the option. May have to try something different, like that.

Comment: This whole upside-down/rightside-up issue is a red herring; all of the coordinates are on the same system so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sat down to figure this out today and it seems to be working. I haven't changed anything. Hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I finally noticed that all the points were sorted by longitude. So either the query (shown above) where I insert the data sorted it, or the query where I select longitude and latitude. The points must be in the correct order or the `contains()` method will not work. My solution will be to add another column to the table so I can number each point. Then whenever I query for the points I will sort by this new column so they are always in the correct order.